# return a string after being concantenated using strcpy and strcat

Tags: c

I am trying to build a function that concatenate two strings and return the concatenated string

here is my current code

```
const char *myName();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *myname = myName();
    printf(myname);
    printf("\n");
}

const char *myName() {
    char *lastname = " lee";
    char *name = "adam";
    char fullname[sizeof(lastname) + sizeof(name)];
    char *test;
  
    strcpy(fullname, name);
    strcat(fullname, lastname);
    test = fullname;

    return test;
}
```

when I printf within the function

```
printf(test)
```

it prints out nicely.
However, when I tried to print out the value after it has been returned

```
printf(myname)
```

nothing prints out.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a VLA stack array.  The lifetime of that array does not extend past the function return.

Comment: Actually, not a VLA, just a char array with automatic storage duration, so still it's gone after the return:(